# print HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, browser, printing

When you print from your browser html page, the text appears at the top of dates and the title page, and below another URL. How to get rid of these texts through JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean the printed page contains a header and footer containing the date, title and URL? If so, you have no control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Those are fixed texts generated by the browser at the print moment, but Firefox for instance has the options not to show them in **page set up** before printing.